# How do I retrieve cookies from a Go webview?

Tags: go, cookies, webview

I'm writing a Go component, and I want to provide personal user login upon startup. This should ideally be done through a webview, which is pulled up when the program starts. This webview should connect to an identity server that is independent of my program. If a login is successful, a cookie containing access + refresh tokens are set in the response. At this point, I want the webview to close, and the tokens to be extracted from the cookies for use in the Go program.

I have tried to achieve this with the webview library [zserge/webview](https://github.com/zserge/webview). However, I have not found a way to extract cookies using this library. The builtin library [net/http](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) has functionality for retrieving cookies - however, the zserge/webview library does not seem to make use of the builtin net/http library.